# Count the inserted div in a for loop

Tags: jquery, file, input

I want to get the total number of divs inserted using a for loop. I wanted to get it to be able to construct a function that will tell the
system that it needs to construct a slider for the images.

Here is my code for inserting a div when a user selects an image file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
        $("#imgupload").on("change", function(e) {
            var files = e.target.files,
            filesLength = files.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
                var f = files[i];
                var fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
                    var file = e.target;
                    $("<div class=img-holder>" +
                        "<button type='button' class='img-close'><img src='../Image/icon-close.png'></button>"+
                        "<img class='upload-img' src='" + e.target.result + "'/>" +
                    "</div").insertAfter("#img-first");
                        $(".img-close").click(function(){
                        $(this).parent(".img-holder").remove();
                    });
                });
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
    }
});
```

I tried doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
        var promises = [];
        var countimg = $("#imgupload").on("change", function(e) {
            var files = e.target.files,
            filesLength = files.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
                var f = files[i];
                var fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
                    var file = e.target;
                    $("<div class=img-holder>" +
                        "<button type='button' class='img-close'><img src='../Image/icon-close.png'></button>"+
                        "<img class='upload-img' src='" + e.target.result + "'/>" +
                    "</div").insertAfter("#img-first");
                        $(".img-close").click(function(){
                        $(this).parent(".img-holder").remove();
                    });
                });
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
            }
        });
        promises.push(countimg);
        $.when.apply(null, promises).done(function(){
            alert($('.img-holder').length);
        })
    } else {
        alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
    }
});
```

But it is not working. It only alerted 0.

Comment: What is the line `promises.push(countimg);` supposed to do? `countimg` is the element with id `imgupload` wrapped in a jQuery object.

Comment: it supposed to count how many times the function finished it action cause, i cant count the div before it is inserted. Am i doing it wrong? Im new to this.